# Use a catalog file in a jar to resolve system DTD

Tags: xml, jar, catalog, dtd

I have some XML files with the declaration DTD:

```
<!DOCTYPE example SYSTEM "file:///c:/dir/example.dtd">
```

I should transform these XML in Linux, so I add a catalog file in my jar:

```
<systemSuffix systemIdSuffix="example.dtd"
uri="models/example/example.dtd"/>
```

example.dtd is also in the jar: models/example/example.dtd

When I transform the XML files with the jar in Linux, I meet exceptions:

```
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3042)
at java.net.URI.(URI.java:588)
at org.xmlresolver.ResourceConnection.(ResourceConnection.java:42)
at org.xmlresolver.ResourceResolver.cacheStreamSystem(ResourceResolver.java:172)
at org.xmlresolver.ResourceResolver.resolveEntity(ResourceResolver.java:296)
at org.xmlresolver.Resolver.resolveEntity(Resolver.java:186)
at org.apache.xerces.util.EntityResolver2Wrapper.resolveEntity(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.resolveEntity(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at net.sf.saxon.event.Sender.sendSAXSource(Sender.java:451)
at net.sf.saxon.event.Sender.send(Sender.java:179)
at net.sf.saxon.Configuration.buildDocumentTree(Configuration.java:3808)
at net.sf.saxon.s9api.DocumentBuilder.build(DocumentBuilder.java:369)
at net.sf.saxon.s9api.DocumentBuilder.build(DocumentBuilder.java:385)
```

How to solve the problem?

Comment: How can this problem be reproduced?

Comment: @mzjn: when I run the program by command line:
java -cp my.jar -Dxml.catalog.files=catalog.xml ..., I met this problem.

Comment: I resolved this problem, I think <systemSuffix> in catalogs isn't recognized by Saxon, it should be replaced by <system> element.